# How to write coditional with null safety in widget tree

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with displaying dynamically Text widget based on String null safety value.
So, If I'm writing conditions like that:

```
String? _selected;
String _placeholer = "select";


         Row(
            children: [
              if (_selected != null) Text(_placeholer) else Text(_selected!),
            ],
          ),
```

or

```
         Row(
            children: [
              _selected!.isEmpty ? Text(_placeholer) : Text(_selected!),
            ],
          ),
```

Console is returning this error:

> Unexpected null value.

And on the view I have red container instead of this Text. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you made a mistake here.

```dart
            children: [
              if (_selected != null) Text(_placeholer) else Text(_selected!),
            ],
```

Change it like this:

```dart
            children: [
              if (_selected == null) Text(_placeholer) else Text(_selected!),
            ],
```

Much better version would be like this:

```dart
children: [
   Text(_selected ?? _placeholder)
]
```

Comment: Boolean expression cannot be null. Give it a default value, and then tou can freely use it like `[ if (_selected) widget1() else widget2()]`